# Mediapipe pose SegmentationMask python javascript differences

Tags: javascript, mediapipe, pose, imagebitmap

I am developing a pose recognition webapp using mediapipe pose library (https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/pose.html).

I am using the segmentationMask to find some specific points of the human body that satisfy a constraint (the value in the n-th pixel must be > 0.1).

I'am able to do this evaluation in python. The library returns the segmentation mask as a matrix with the same width and height as the input image, and contains values in [0.0, 1.0] where 1.0 and 0.0 indicate high certainty of a “human” and “background” pixel respectively. So I can iterate over the matrix and I am able to find the point that satisfy the constraint.

I am trying to do the same thing in javascript, but I have a problem. The The javascript version of the library does not return a matrix but returns an ImageBitmap used by the html canvas to draw the mask.
The problem is that with ImageBitmap I cannot access every point of the matrix and I am not able to find the points I am interested in.

Is there a way to transform the javascript segmentationMask ImageBitmap in order be similar to the segmenationMask of the python versione library or at least retrive the same informations (I need the values included in this range [0.0, 1.0] for every pixel of the image).

Thank you all.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is unfortunately no direct way to get an ImageData from an ImageBitmap, but you can `drawImage()` this ImageBitmap on a clear canvas and then call `ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)` to retrieve an ImageData where you'll get access to all the pixels data.

The confidence will be stored in the Alpha channel (every fourth item in `imageData.data`) as a value between `0` and `255`.

```
function onResults(results) {
  canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
  canvasCtx.drawImage(results.segmentationMask, 0, 0,
                      canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
  const imgData = canvasCtx.getImageData(0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
  let i = 0;
  for (let y = 0; y<imgData.height; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x<imgData.width; x++) {
      const confidence = imgData.data[i + 3];
      // do something with confidence here
      i++;
    }
  }
}
```

And since you're gonna read a lot from that context, don't forget to pass the `willReadFrequently` option when you get it.

[As a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zr1x86Ln/) since StackSnippets won't allow the use of the camera.

---

Note that depending on what you do you may want to colorize this image from red to black using `globalCompositeOperation` and treat the data as an `Uint32Array` where the confidence would be expressed between `0` and `0xFF000000`.

Comment: Hi Kaiido,
Just what I was searching for, thank you so muck. 
I was going crazy trying to get confidence informations back from the ImageBitmap.
I am searching to find the first human point on the back when the user is sideways in front of the cam.

The problem is that I don't want to draw the segmentation mask on the screen.
Is there a walk around like drawing trasparent segmentation mask o something like that?

However you saved my day, thank you so much.

Comment: Hi Kaiido,
when I try to get the canvas context with {  willReadFrequently: true } my angular code does not compile, here the errors:

Property 'getImageData' does not exist on type 'ImageBitmapRenderingContext'.
Property 'save' does not exist on type 'ImageBitmapRenderingContext'.
...
My Question is: why getting the context with   willReadFrequently returns ImageBitmapRenderingContext ?

Comment: You passed "2d" as first argument right? There is no reason you'd get a bitmap renderer in such a case. That would be a (bad) browser bug. Which browser are you experiencing it with?

Comment: yes I pass "2d" as first argument. 
I develop on Chrome but the error is shown on vscode console. As soon as I add { willReadFrequently: true }, the codes recompile and throws these type of errors on every function and variable:

ERROR in src/app/pages/player/player.component.ts:322:17 - error TS2339: Property 'save' does not exist on 
type 'RenderingContext'.
  Property 'save' does not exist on type 'ImageBitmapRenderingContext'.

But it's vscode that throws these errors in console. I don't know why

Comment: It's a problem on my IDE sorry.
On the browser works great.
Thank you for the support. 
Is there away to improve performance?